# Inference based on multiple hypothesis tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

This might be a rather basic question, but I really want to get it right.

When doing **multiple hypothesis testing**, researchers typically account for the "multiple" part by controlling for the **family wise error rate** by means of e.g. the Bonferroni Correction procedure.

However, is it possible to make a "summarizing" inference based on the hypothesis test results of multiple tests? Say, for example, I conducted a hypothesis test repeatedly for 5 times. I controlled for the family wise error rate by adjusting each p-value by applying the Bonferroni Correction procedure. In 3 cases I reject the null hypothesis, in 2 cases I do not.

Can I reject or accept the null hypothesis "in general" based on this result? I.e. can I summarize those 5 test results in some way?

Comment: An **omnibus null hypothesis**, for example, of the form $\text{H}_{0}\text{: }\theta_{i} = \theta_{j}$, for all $i \ne j$, and $i, j$ index groups $1$ through $k$, where $\text{H}_{\text{A}}\text{: }\theta_{i} \ne \theta_{j}$ for at least one $i \ne j$ summarizes differences across all pairwise combinations of $k$ groups. For example, one-way ANOVA, Kruskal-Wallis, etc. are omnibus tests. Are you asking about this?

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it still helps - thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Often, a "summary" test refers to a test of a global hypothesis. In your case, if your global hypothesis is "All five nulls are true," and then if you reject *at least one hypothesis* using the Bonferroni criterion, then you have successfully rejected the global hypothesis.  Often a (summary) p-value is attached to such a test; in your case the p-value would be the Bonferroni-adjusted p-value for the most significant result; i.e., $p_{adjusted} = 5\min p_i$, where $i = 1,2,3,4,5$, and the $p_i$ refer to the ordinary (unadjusted) p-values for each of the five tests.

This method generalizes easily to account for dependence structures and non-normalities; see e.g. [https://www.amazon.com/Resampling-Based-Multiple-Testing-Examples-Adjustment/dp/0471557617](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471557617)

Comment: Another global hypothesis is that at least one of the nulls are true.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.